# Header already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, field

Hi i have this code to create a custom repetable field ina metabox in wordpress post edit screen.

Works perfectly but when i delete all fields with the button 'remove' that is in jquery function and save the post it gives me the following error:

```
    Notice: Undefined index: medias in /home1/mimo/public_html/demos/newtheme/wp-content/plugins/mimo-media/mimo-media.php on line 104

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/mimo/public_html/demos/newtheme/wp-content/plugins/mimo-media/mimo-media.php:104) in /home1/mimo/public_html/demos/newtheme/wp-admin/post.php on line 222

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/mimo/public_html/demos/newtheme/wp-content/plugins/mimo-media/mimo-media.php:104) in /home1/mimo/public_html/demos/newtheme/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875
```

My code goes like this in the mimo-media.php file, the error in line 104 is just at the end of the file, where it ends  ?¿?¿:

It seems when the field is empty it gives the error, but not the first time you open the post(and the field is empty), only when saving it after deleting all fields.

Thank you very much for your attention.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
add_meta_box(
    'dynamic_sectionid',
    __( 'Add Media(Images and Vimeo or Youtube Videos urls', 'one' ),
    'mimo_custom_media',
    'post');
}

/* Prints the box content */
function mimo_custom_media() {
global $post;
// Use nonce for verification
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
?>
<div id="meta_inner">
<?php

//get the saved meta as an arry
$medias = get_post_meta($post->ID,'medias',true);

$c = 0;
if ( count( $medias ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $medias as $track ) {
        if ( isset( $track['title'] ) ) {
            printf( '<p>Media url <input type="text" name="medias[%1$s][title]"   value="%2$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $track['title'], '', __( 'Remove Media' ) );
            $c = $c +1;
        }
    }
}
?>
<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('Add Tracks'); ?></span>
<script>
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
    $(".add").click(function() {
        count = count + 1;

        $('#here').append('<p> Media url <input type="text" name="medias['+count+'][title]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Media</span></p>' );
        return false;
    });
    $(".remove").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
</div><?php

}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
// verify if this is an auto save routine. 
// If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;

// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
    return;

if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    return;

// OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
if($_POST['medias']){$medias = $_POST['medias'];}


update_post_meta($post_id,'medias',$medias);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to happen when it's not set or is it empty?

```
if(isset($_POST['medias']) && !empty($_POST['medias'])){
    $medias = $_POST['medias'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'medias',$medias);
} else {
    //no $medis so do what?
}
```

Comment: Hi abracadaver, i have tried this but get the same error. Do i have to include something in the else when there are no medias? Thank you

Comment: Well you don't have 104 lines of code posted, which is where the error is so I assumed since that was the only $_POST['medias'].  You added the isset() and there isn't another reference to $_POST['medias'] in the code?

Comment: Hi, finally solved it including the var declaration inside else:'if(isset($_POST['medias']) && !empty($_POST['medias'])){
    $medias = $_POST['medias'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'medias',$medias);
} else {
     $medias = '';
     update_post_meta($post_id,'medias',$medias);}

}'

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['medias']) && !empty($_POST['medias'])){` is identical to `if(!empty($_POST['medias'])){`, so no need for `isset` part.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely $medias is not defined when it hits line 104. Either create $medias as an empty variable at the start of function dynamic_save_postdata(), or put update_post_meta in the brackets here:

```
if($_POST['medias']){
    $medias = $_POST['medias'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'medias',$medias);
}
```

Comment: Hi aynber, this solution gives me the same error ?¿? Thank you very much